# Nash equilibrium of mixed strategies

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have found 2 pure Nash equilibria in the following game which are (Y,B) & (Z,C)

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X** | 6 , 0 | 0 , 3 | 1 , 8 |
| **Y** | 3 , 4 | 1 , 5 | 1 , 3 |
| **Z** | 7 , 2 | 0 , 1 | 2 , 3 |

I am looking for mixed strategy Nash Equilibria.

Let A probability be $p_1$, B probability be $p_2$, and C probability be $1−p_1−p_2$.

$ EU(X)=6p_1+1-p_1-p_2 = 5p_1-p_2+1 $

$ EU(Y)=3p_1+p_2+1-p_1-p_2 = 2p_1+1 $

$ EU(Z)=7p_1+2-2p_1-2p_2=5p_1-2p_2+2$

From these 3 equations I get:

$p_1=1/3, p_2=1$ which does not make sense as a probability distribution.

If I follow the same approach for the other player:

Let X probability be $q_1$, Y probability be $q_2$, and Z probability be $1−q_1−q_2$.

$EU(A)= 4q_2+2-2q_1-2q_2=-2q_1+2q_2+2$

$EU(B)= 3q_1+5q_2+1-q_1-q_2=2q_1+4q_2+1$

$EU(C)= 8q_1+3q_2+3-3q_1-3q_2 = 5q_1+3$

Form these 3 equations I get:

$q_1=0, q_2=0.5$

I am not sure how to interpret these results. Is there a Nash equilibrium of mixed strategies here?

Comment: Do you observe that $X$ for player $1$ is strictly dominated by a mixture of $Y$ and $Z$? This means that in any Nash equilibrium, $X$ must be played with probability $0$. You can then start from here to find out the equilibria.

Comment: Actually the result of the calculations gave probability of X as $q_1=0$ which matches with your comment.However, I can't interpret the results for player 2.

Comment: When I try removing the first row, the equations don't seem to give results for the probability distribution of player 2. I end up with $ 2p_1+1=5p_1-2p_2+2$